# How to handle user control button click event to parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have user control NumericKeyPad on the FormStart and I need, that when I click on button e.g. button3 (with Tag value: 3) on the Formstart textBoxEmployee# it writes 3 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom event in the `UserControl`, handle button click and raise it from there. Then, from the parent form, handle your custom event of `UserControl`. To illustrate, here is a code sample (VB.NET - I am not very good at C#):

```
Public Class UserControl1
  Public Event ButtonClicked(tag As Object)
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
    RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(CType(sender, Button).Tag)
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub UserControl11_ButtonClicked(tag As Object) Handles UserControl11.ButtonClicked
    TextBox1.Text = tag
  End Sub
End Class
```